# Which is the most suitable stage in the DirectShow pipeline to initialize a resource?

Tags: c++, directshow, video-capture

I'm programming a DirectShow filter that reads data from a cam. I wonder which is the most suitable point on the whole DirectShow pipeline to initialize this cam. On the filter pause method, on the OnThreadCreate overrided method... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what exactly "cam initialization" is. If it is something trivial and simple, you can do it any time. Should this be related to runtime delay and/or exclusive resource management, then you don't want to do it too early because you don't want an idling instantiated filter to produce errors and cause unexpected freezes. It makes sense to do this sort of initialization on UI action (filter or pin property pages) or transition from stopped state (`CSourceStream::OnThreadCreate` looks good), whatever takes place first.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a straight forward initialization, you should do it as early as possible - constructor.

Make sure the factory function for your filter checks that the constructor was successful by exposing an "IsOK" function. The camera might be disconnected and you want to catch that early - before the filter is connected.